# Combining Two Separate WebScraped lists in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am web scraping data from a car website to get prices. Right now, I am approaching the problem by creating two separate lists; one of the pricing data and another for the model of the car. Ultimately, I want to take each list and join the two together to create a CSV. 
The specific steps I am taking to solve this problem are the following:

1. Establishing a connection to the website
2. Creating two empty lists to write the data into
3. Selecting the correct data from each part of the page
4. Iterating over the data and storing that data into a list (This is where I'm having problems)
5. Eventually, I am going to join the two lists together as one CSV.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

#1) establishing a connection to the website
wiki = "http://www.morong.com/used-inventory/index.htm?start=16&"
req = urllib2.Request(wiki)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

#2) creating two empty lists to write the data into
valueHolder = []
nameHolder = []

#3) selecting the correct data from each part of the page 
value = soup.findAll("span", { "class" : "value" })

name = soup.findAll("a", {"class" : "url"})

#4) iterates over rows and turns each row into a text field
for row in value:
    valueholder = row.text

for row in name:
    nameHolder = row.text
print(valueholder)
print(nameHolder)
```

When I print `valueHolder` and `nameHolder`, I only return the last row of each for-loop. How can I print all of the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use zip() function to connect those two lists:

```
value = [row.text for row in value]   
name = [row.text for row in name]
zipped_value_name = list(zip(value, name))

for row in zipped_value_name:
    print(row)
```

You can also create dictionary instead of list `dict_not_list = dict((zip(name, value))`

Comment: I was going to answer the question. But I think this is what the OP needs

Answer (score 1):

You're re-assigning the `valueHolder` and `nameHolder` identifiers in your loops instead of adding elements to the lists. Try this:

```
for row in value:
          valueHolder.append(row.text)    
     for row in name:
         nameHolder.append(row.text)
```

To combine the lists you could use a `map`, such as in

```
combinations = list(map(lambda x,y: [x,y], nameHolder, valueHolder))
```

Comment: Congratulations, you just reinvented the builtin `zip()` function <g>

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
for row in value:
    valueholder = row.text
    print(valueholder)

for row in name:
    nameHolder = row.text
    print(nameHolder)
```

Comment: "Bureaucrat Conrad you are technically correct ... The best kind of correct. "

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from rebinding (reassigning to) your `valueHolder` and `nameHolder` variables in your loop:

```
# here you bind `valueHolder` to an empty list
valueHolder = []
value = soup.findAll("span", { "class" : "value" })
for row in value:
    # here you rebind it to `row.text` (loosing the empty list)
    valueHolder = row.text
```

What you want is to append to the lists instead:

```
valueHolder = []
value = soup.findAll("span", { "class" : "value" })
for row in value:
    valueHolder.append(row.text)
```

To combine both lists, you can use `zip()`:

```
result = zip(nameHolder, valueHolder)
```

which will create a list of `(name, value)` tuples.

This being said, instead of doing two distinct lookup/loops appending to two distinct lists, you would be better iterating on the parents elements (the element in your source markup that holds both the 'value' span and the 'name' link) and build one single list of `(name, value)` tuple:

```
results = []
for item in soup.findAll("li", {"class":"item"}):
    value = soup.find("span", { "class" : "value" }).text
    name = soup.find("a", {"class" : "url"}).text
    results.append((name, value))
```

This way you are reasonably sure name and value will really match, which migh not necessarily be the case with your solution.